# Consolidating JUnit results through SBT

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, junit, sbt

First some background : I have a remote jenkins that performs some Newman tests on my web app built with PlayFramework. Results are consolidated in an xml file and displayed with the "test results analyzer" plugin in Jenkins. This is ok.

Now, I would like to add some JUnit tests to my web app and, if possible, I would like to write the new results in the same xml file so as to see all results in the same report.

As a first step, I've been trying to run JUnit tests localy and to save results in a specific file. I can run my JUnit tests, but I cannot save the results in an xml file.

Could you please help me a bit?

**JUnit test:**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;

public class Benchmark {

    @Test
    public void dummy() {
        assertTrue(1+1 == 2);
        System.out.println("Test has been done");
    }
}
```

**Command to run the JUnit test :**

```
sbt clean compile test
```

**Terminal output :**

```
[success] Total time: 11 s, completed 18 sept. 2018 12:54:34
Test has been done
```

**build.sbt :**

```
name := """WebApp"""
organization := "com.organization"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
sbtVersion := "1.1.1"

logLevel := Level.Warn

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx3g", "-Xms3g")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...,
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10" % "test"
)
```

As a second step, I would like to make it work on my remote Jenkins. If it works locally, it should be easy to make it work remotely, but just in case, below is my **Jenkins configuration for the build step** :

```
rm -r /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebApp/target/universal/*

cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebApp
sbt -J-Xmx3G -J-Xms3G dist

cd target/universal
unzip webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip

cd webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT
chmod u+x bin/webapp

bash bin/webapp -Dhttp.port=9004 -J-Xms3g -J-Xmx3g &
sleep 10
newman run /home/tests/WebApp-Jenkins-Tests.postman_collection.json --reporters junit,cli --reporter-junit-export /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebApp/testResults/results.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, I've found a solution. Instead of specifying the output of JUnit, I've changed the output of newman so that newman writes results in the same folder as Junit.

**Jenkins configuration :**

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebApp

sbt clean compile test

sbt -J-Xmx3G -J-Xms3G dist
cd target/universal
unzip webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
cd webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT
chmod u+x bin/webapp

bash bin/webapp -Dhttp.port=9004 -J-Xms3g -J-Xmx3g &
sleep 10
newman run /home/tests/Jenkins-Tests.postman_collection.json --reporters junit,cli --reporter-junit-export /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WebApp/target/test-reports/newmanTests.xml
```

Also, even if I do not know if it helps, I've updated sbt to 1.2.3.
Now it works just fine :)